# Refresh a div after successful AJAX operation in Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I want to `refresh/update` my `div` when a successful `ajax` operation occurs. But I've no exact idea how to do that.

Clearly, I can say that my `div` should show the `inserted` data after the successful insertion operation done by `ajax`. And it obviously should be done without loading page.

I'm attaching what I've tried so far.

`Route(web.php)`

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['only' => ['store']]);
```

`Cotroller(PostsController)`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'post' => 'required|min:20',
    ));

    $post=new Post();
    $post->userId=Auth::user()->id;
    $post->post=$request->post;
    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

`Controller(PagesController)`

```
public function getHome(){
    $posts=Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('pages.home')->withPosts($posts);
}
```

`JS`

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),

    success: function(response){
        $('.all-posts-body').load(); //No idea how to do this
    },
})
```

`Views(home.blade)`

```
<div class="all-posts-body">
    @if($posts->isEmpty())
        <div class="alert alert-warning">No post yet!</div>
    @else
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {!! nl2br($post->post) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

This `.all-posts-body` should be refreshed without reloading page whenever I insert a post by ajax.

I'm attaching a sample image for better explanation
[image]

Comment: The response parameter in your success callback contains the data returned by the ajax response, you need to use that to "refresh" your div

Comment: Yes, probably I'm looking for that. Whats the perfect solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the HTML content that you want from the backend and replace the `success` with

```
 success: function(response){
    $('.all-posts-body').html(response);
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make something like this (i prefer to use id not class)

```
    $('#all-posts-body').load(location.href+(' #all-posts-body'));
```

and please add space before your id